# Compare XML in JAVA, output: changelog

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, compare

I am searching for a solution to compare two slightly different XML's (they are generated automatically and one has a later version than the other one, meaning there are just a few more lines).
After they have been compared, something like a changelog or even better a new XML with coloured changes would be needed.
I am working with JAVA in Eclipse and as this is pretty new for me I am asking here kind of clueless.

Comment: Do you want to write a program to do this, or do you just need an interactive solution in a tool, maybe even within Eclipse?

Comment: I actually want to write a program to do this, maybe using DOM or SAX parser? I am really not yet into this and need good advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a library to implement xml-diff in your application, you should check this one: http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/